# Rails 3 Select_tag in javascript give missing ; error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

When I write

```
var x = "<%= select_tag(:activity_group, options_for_select(activity_grp),{:include_blank => 'Create New Group', :style => 'width: 100px'}) %>";
```

and

```
<% activity_grp = @activity_group.map { |ag| [ag.name, ag.id] } %>
```

However, I get error (missing ; before statement) in Firebug because

```
var x = "<select id="activity_group" name="activity_group" style="width: 100px"><option value="">Create New Group</option><option value="1">Movie</option>

 <option value="2">Report</option>";
```

the code generated takes more than one line. I tried html_safe as well it does not works

Can anyone guide me who came across this error before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you do with `x`? Can this be moved into a partial? In any case, you're not trying to HTML-safe it, you're trying to [JavaScript-safe](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) it.

Comment: I think this method does not do what I think it does.

Comment: So I am creating dynamic drop down box from DB and it used in many popover forms. SO, I am storing that <select> in variable and will be using it in another forms as well.

Answer (score 0):

As per Dave answer, I solved it by JavaScript-safe

```
<% @x = select_tag(:activity_group, options_for_select(activity_grp),{:include_blank => 'Create New Group', :style => 'width: 100px'}) %>
```

and then in my JS area i wrote

```
var abc = "<%= escape_javascript(@x)%>";
```

it work fine. Hope this help